# Laravel file cache: can we set file permissions?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I ask you if there is the possibility to add a permission mask to `config/cache.php` so new cache file are created with 664 and not with 644 as file permission mask.

My shell use is also member of `www-data` group, but with a 644, shell user cannot delete cache.

Comment: Have you tried giving a recursive read and write permission on the storage cache folder to the www-data group?

Comment: Yes. New files are anyway created using www-data:www-data with 644. Of course, I can use sudo to workaround this problem, but it's not my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the file store driver, laravel creates the driver with reading a setting for file permissions from your config [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Cache/CacheManager.php#L158):

```
protected function createFileDriver(array $config)
{
    return $this->repository(new FileStore($this->app['files'], $config['path'], $config['permission'] ?? null));
}
```

That means you can specify file permission by adding the key "permission" in `config/cache.php` like:

```
    'stores' =>[
        ...
        'file' => [
            'driver' => 'file',
            ...
            'permission' => 0664,
        ],
     ]
```

Make sure to specify the permission with a leading `0` so it is correctly interpreted. That is as phps [chmod](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.chmod.php) function is used internally.

I tested this with laravel 9, but did not check if this behavior is different in older versions.

Comment: When your interactive user is not the same as that of the web server (usually `www-data`), you may want to use `0774` and add your user to the `www-data` group to be able to clear the cache.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new file cache store instance or custom cache driver. Then set your permission.

Laravel [File Store Documentation](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Cache/FileStore.php#L46)

```
__construct(Filesystem $files, string $directory, int|null $filePermission = null)
```

$filePermission accepts int|null

```
namespace App\Extensions;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Store;

class CustomStore implements Store
{
  public function __construct(Filesystem $files, string $directory, int|null $filePermission = null) {}
  public function get($key) {}
  public function many(array $keys) {}
  public function put($key, $value, $seconds) {}
  public function putMany(array $values, $seconds) {}
  public function increment($key, $value = 1) {}
  public function decrement($key, $value = 1) {}
  public function forever($key, $value) {}
  public function forget($key) {}
  public function flush() {}
  public function getPrefix() {}
}
```

After creating a custom cache driver, you can register it see [instructions](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/cache#writing-the-driver)

Comment: Damn, I never thought to write a custom cache driver...  I thank you but I'll wait for another reply

Comment: You can extend existed and rewrite only mask. Than register.